# PySpark : Having trouble matching a date column to a dictionary

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am certain this is a simple change but having issues simply matching a date column to a list of items. Example is using the holidays package but the problem can be applied to other use cases, just my experience in PySpark is not great!!

Using the holidays package (https://pypi.org/project/holidays/) I retrieve a dict of holidays

```
nyse_holidays=holidays.financial.ny_stock_exchange.NewYorkStockExchange(years=2018)
print(nyse_holidays)
```

*{datetime.date(2018, 12, 5): 'Day of Mourning for President George H.W. Bush', datetime.date(2018, 1, 1): "New Year's Day", datetime.date(2018, 1, 15): 'Martin Luther King Jr. Day', datetime.date(2018, 2, 19): "Washington's Birthday", datetime.date(2018, 3, 30): 'Good Friday', datetime.date(2018, 5, 28): 'Memorial Day', datetime.date(2018, 7, 4): 'Independence Day', datetime.date(2018, 9, 3): 'Labor Day', datetime.date(2018, 11, 22): 'Thanksgiving Day', datetime.date(2018, 12, 25): 'Christmas Day'}
*

I also have another Spark data frame with the following schema

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- year: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- month: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- day: string (nullable = false)
 |-- day_of_year: string (nullable = false)
 |-- hour: string (nullable = false)
 |-- minute: string (nullable = false)
 |-- is_weekend: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- only_date: date (nullable = false)
```

I simply want to add another field saying if the date for that row is a holiday or not

The following code never matches any dates

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit
from itertools import chain

mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*nyse_holidays.items())])
#search_date
display(df.withColumn("value", mapping_expr["only_date"]).filter(col("value").isNotNull()))
```

If I change the code to a fixed value to check the mapping_expr works then it works fine.

```
search_date = datetime.strptime('2018-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
display(df.withColumn("value", mapping_expr[search_date]).filter(col("value").isNotNull()))
```

Preferbably the code would just use the 'date' field but I thought I would create a only_date field.

Any recommendations, sure I am just missing something silly.  Assuming its the conversion of the field being past into the mapping_expr

Answer (score 0):

Simple as just passing in col("only_date"), in the mapping expression.

Long few days with other things! Mind not focused, give me c#! :)